# How to implement multi-tenancy in mongo db using morphia

Tags: mongodb, morphia

Multi-tenancy on the database level: One way to separate data for multiple clients is to have individual databases per tenant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you are working on webservice or web application.

1. A client will send tenant id as header parameter.
2. Write one filter and get the tenant details from the Cache by tenant id.
3. Set the schema name in the filter 
   for example:

   ```
   MDC.put(Constants.MONGO_TENANT_DB, "uat");
   ```
4. MongoMultiTenancyInterceptor will get called before any DB operation/orm call.
   String tenantDBName = MDC.get(Constants.MONGO_TENANT_DB);

   ```
     LOG.info("Switching to database:  "+tenantDBName);
     if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(tenantDBName)){
             MultitenantDatastoreFactory.setDatabaseNameForCurrentThread(tenantDBName);
     }
     Setting the Database name for current Thread.
   ```
5. MultitenantDatastoreFactory : Create datastore instance per tenant schema and store into HashMap.
6. MultitenantDatastoreFactory.getDS(): Returns the datastore from the Hashmap by schema name
7. UserRepository: It will get Datastore object from the factory method and perform any DB operation.

I have uploaded my project in GITHUB, you can download the code from GITHUB

https://github.com/vikashnitk50/spring-morphia-db-poc